# What causes a "NO UID SEARCH State error"

Tags: imap

I have a script that connects via TCP/Sockets, Authenticates SSL, and then checks if the response from stream returns "OK".
It then sends a UID search command:
`{tag} UID SEARCH (UNDELETED) (SENTSINCE "{RFC2060 Format Date}")`

I then follow that with another `OK` check aswell as a `* SEARCH` stream response check.
When both of those are not true, I always end up with this as a result from the stream: `xm005 NO UID SEARCH State error`

Im not certain but is it possible this returns if the email has no UNDELETED inbox or something?

---

This seems to occur all the time on one of my chinese friends specific accounts on yeah.net (163-China related email service).

When I login to it with Windows 10's Mail App, I can see it has inboxes in CHINESE. Is it possible something to do with that is causing this issue?

[image]

I'm essentially wanting to search for every email within the sent-since date that has not been deleted, perhaps (UNDELETED) isn't a global declaration and is an actual inbox or something?

---

According to IMAPv4.1's RFC:

```
UNDELETED
Messages that do not have the \Deleted flag set.
```

So maybe its not to do with Inbox's? regardless its pretty odd that both emails this occurs on have Chinese Inbox's yet my English-Only one works splendid.

---

I removed `(UNDELETED)` and attempted running, and the same issue occurs, so it's not that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "state" in the error message could mean "your state does not include a mailbox". Make sure to issue a `SELECT` command before `UID SEARCH`.

Comment: My bad! I totally forgot about mention that I do indeed select a Mailbox. I select "INBOX", perhaps thats why? In Windows 10 Mail, it to cant find any emails in "INBOX", yet the Chinese Named inboxes do find emails. So I guess I got to manually choose one of the Chinese Named inboxes in this situation? :l

Comment: Odd, this is the response when selecting, So I guess a Mailbox wasnt selected after all? https://i.imgur.com/IjQNbWf.png

Comment: The server very likely insists that you use TLS, and refuses to open a mailbox for a cleartext connection.

Comment: BTW, it's considered good to use text instead of (or in addition to) screenshots on Stack Overflow. People google for error messages, such as the message in your imgur screenshot, and they should find the SO questions where people have solved the errors.

Comment: I connect with TCP and then use the .GetStream() and convert that to SslStream and I provide it all TLS protocols, for servers like that, it would still work then right as I use the TLS Protocols when making the SslStream?

Comment: That's not an IMAP question and quite far from this question. I suggest that you post a new question tagged with the networking library you use and perhaps the programming language. Include code.

Comment: This error message looks like it the security systems have decided your app is not 'safe'; we're not able to tell you why because it's provider-specific and changes over time.

Comment: @Max and Arnt, Im not 100% sure, but after checking, it seems its an IP Address thing, some sort of security measure from logging in, basically the email is marked as insecure and essentially locked/disabled, thats most likely the issue, thanks everyone.